# How to check activity log of Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I want to monitor Activity Logs on Oracle SQL Developer Tool, using `F8` key i am getting SQL history.

I want user session-wise data like who (user) have executed which query or any operation from GUI.

Answer (score 5):

```
To view sessions:
```

In SQL Developer, click Tools, then Monitor Sessions.

In the Select Connection dialog box, select a connection to SYSTEM (or another account with full DBA privileges)

```
A Sessions tab is displayed
```

[image]